Correspondence of forms of the same solution of a system of linear equations
I am currently reading Mathematics for Machine Learning book (p.27-28, freely available). And I am really confused with how two different forms of a solution of a system of linear equations correspond to each other. So, here is a problem presented by authors.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 8 & -4\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 12
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
42 \\
8
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Authors right down the general solution in the following way:
$$
\textbf{x} =
\begin{bmatrix}
42 \\
8 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \lambda_1
\begin{bmatrix}
8 \\
2 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+ \lambda_2
\begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
12 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, the general solution also can be written this way (as I remember from university):
$$
x_1 = 42 - 8x_3 + 4x_4 \\
x_2 = 8 - 2x_3 - 12x_4
$$
Where $x_3$ and $x_4$ are free variables. 
I think I understand these forms of the solution seperately but I cannot connect them into one mental model inside my head. In the first form each row corresponds to the value of $x_i$ respectively but at the same time these values are just multipliers to $x_j$ in the seocnd form (for instance, 8 is a value of $x_1$ in the second summand in the first form but it is also just a constant for $x_3$ in the first row of the second form). It is also not clear why the signs are inverse for the second form (e.g. 8 vs -8). 
Could you please explain your vision on how these forms are connected and answer my questions if they are clear enough.

We will see how to go from second form to first form.
We have
$$
x_1 = 42 - 8x_3 + 4x_4 \\
x_2 = 8 - 2x_3 - 12x_4
$$
From this, it is clear that $x_3$ and $x_4$ are free variables. So, we will write all the terms $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ in terms of $x_3, x_4$.
So, we have,
$$
x_1 = 42 - 8x_3 + 4x_4 \\
x_2 = 8 - 2x_3 - 12x_4 \\
x_3=0+x_3+0x_4 \\
x_4=0+0x_3+x_4
$$
So, we have,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
42 - 8x_3 + 4x_4 \\
8 - 2x_3 - 12x_4 \\
0+x_3+0x_4 \\
0+0x_3+x_4
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
42 \\
8 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+ (-x_3)
\begin{bmatrix}
8 \\
2 \\
-1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
+(-x_4)
\begin{bmatrix}
-4 \\
12 \\
0 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
No harm in writing $-x_3=\lambda_1$, $-x_4=\lambda_2$, which gives us first form.
